# Compile a file when images are missing/not available

Tags: graphics, draft

I don't have access to my image files so I want to only compile with the text. I figured using `draft` mode would solve this problem but I still get a "cannot find image file" error.

How can I compile without having to copy some random picture I *do* have.

Here is my header

```
\newcommand{\rootFolder}{/home/pa06r/pa06r-thesis}

\documentclass{\rootFolder/latex_templates/tex/latex/ecsdocs/ecsthesis}      

\graphicspath{{\rootFolder/images/}}  % Location of your graphics files

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}     %Use for graphics

\usepackage{subfigure}      %Use for side-by-side figures

\usepackage{float}      % Use for floating figuress

\usepackage[round]{natbib}      % Use Natbib style for the refs.

\usepackage{multirow}       %Use for multirow tables

\usepackage{rotating}       %Use for rotating tables

\usepackage{colortbl}       %Use for coloring table backgrounds

\usepackage{algorithmic}    %Use for algorithms

\usepackage{algorithm}      %Use for algorithm labels

\usepackage{ulem}       %Use for strikethroughs

\usepackage{listings}       %Use for Pseudocode

\usepackage{color}      %package listings needs this

\usepackage{textcomp}       %Used for tilde character

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}    %Set to false for black/white printing

\usepackage{lscape}     %For rotating pages with long images
```

---

Minimal example as per Joseph Wrights request. I created a `.tex`file with the following

```
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{'img.jpg'}
\end{document}
```

Here is the log file

```
This is pdfeTeX, Version 3.141592-1.21a-2.2 (Web2C 7.5.4) (format=pdflatex 2010.5.13)  5 OCT 2011 22:08
entering extended mode
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2003/12/01>
Babel <v3.8d> and hyphenation patterns for american, french, german, ngerman, b
ahasa, basque, bulgarian, catalan, croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, e
stonian, finnish, greek, icelandic, irish, italian, latin, magyar, norsk, polis
h, portuges, romanian, russian, serbian, slovak, slovene, spanish, swedish, tur
kish, ukrainian, nohyphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2001/07/07 v1.0n Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2005/02/03 v1.3 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)

! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `demo' for package `graphics'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.72 \if
        !\Gin@driver!
? 
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 80.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2002/06/19 v0.03k graphics/color for pdftex
\Gread@gobject=\count79
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen102
\Gin@req@width=\dimen103
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2004/02/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2004/02/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen104
)
No file test.aux.
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.tex
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/context/base/supp-mis.tex
loading : Context Support Macros / Miscellaneous (2004.10.26)
\protectiondepth=\count88
\scratchcounter=\count89
\scratchtoks=\toks15
\scratchdimen=\dimen105
\scratchskip=\skip43
\scratchmuskip=\muskip10
\scratchbox=\box26
\scratchread=\read1
\scratchwrite=\write3
\zeropoint=\dimen106
\onepoint=\dimen107
\onebasepoint=\dimen108
\minusone=\count90
\thousandpoint=\dimen109
\onerealpoint=\dimen110
\emptytoks=\toks16
\nextbox=\box27
\nextdepth=\dimen111
\everyline=\toks17
\!!counta=\count91
\!!countb=\count92
\recursecounter=\count93
)
loading : Context Support Macros / PDF (2004.03.26)
\nofMPsegments=\count94
\nofMParguments=\count95
\MPscratchCnt=\count96
\MPscratchDim=\dimen112
\MPnumerator=\count97
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks18
)

LaTeX Warning: File `'img.jpg'' not found on input line 4.


! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .jpg'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 \includegraphics{'img.jpg'}

? 
(./test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 868 strings out of 94500
 10335 string characters out of 1176766
 56775 words of memory out of 1000000
 4098 multiletter control sequences out of 10000+50000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 500000 for 2000
 580 hyphenation exceptions out of 1000
 25i,1n,19p,220b,36s stack positions out of 1500i,500n,5000p,200000b,5000s
PDF statistics:
 0 PDF objects out of 300000
 0 named destinations out of 131072
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 65536

No pages of output.
```

Comment: I tried all variations of `demo` and `draft` for both `graphicx`and `documentclass`and I even tried compiling with `pdflatex -draftmode` but I still get `cannot find image file...fatal error occoured`.

Comment: Perhaps try deleting the `.aux` file and use @JosephWright's answer again.

Comment: @Werner I deleted all `.aux` files and it still didn't work

Comment: You're not compiling with `pdftex` (or `pdflatex`), are you? Could this be the problem? I've never delved into this...

Comment: @Werner yes I am compiling with pdflatex...is that a bad thing

Comment: @puk From your updated question, I see that you have a *very* old installation (your `graphics` is 6 years old). The `demo` option was added many years ago to help with cases like yours. You could install `graphics` 'locally', but as it is such a core part of LaTeX I'd suggest your better updating your TeX system.

Comment: @puk: Further to Joseph's comment, note the date of your file `graphics.sty`: `2001/07/07`. Even in TeX Live 2009 (via [ScribTeX](http://www.scribtex.com)), this file has a date of `2009/02/05`.

Comment: @JosephWright that's not an option it's the central server. I will try a different server, I hope that works. Thank you for your help

Comment: @JosephWright Just to conclude, I downloaded the newest graphics and graphicx files and it works.

Answer (score 15):

The `demo` option for the `graphicx` package is your friend

```
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
```

will insert a square black 'blob' in place of the real images, and will not search for them. (The `draft` option does not include images, but does find out how big they are, which still requires the files.)

The `demo` option ignores the files entirely. Thus all of the 'blobs' are the same size, unless there was an explicit height or width given as an argument to `\includegraphics`.

---

A short demo of how to do this before loading a class (which might then load `graphic(s|x)`):

```
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{whatever}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is still not working. I am using `pdflatex`, would that make a difference?

Comment: @puk As you are using a non-standard class, you may need to `\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}` before the `\documentclass` line. This will sort out any issue if the document class requires the package.

Comment: I am encountering a host of problems. it says unknown option demo for graphicx. Do I still need to include the `usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` line?

Comment: sorry, it says unknown option demo for graphics (not graphicx)

Comment: @puk Please try the minimal demo I've added to my answer. if that fails, we'll need to see a log file: Run my example and add the log to your question.