# Print frames rather than boxes with demo/draft version of graphics/graphicx

Tags: graphics, draft

I [recently](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30591/compile-a-file-when-images-are-missing-not-available) switched to `demo` such that I could compile my `.tex` file without needing the actual image files. Now, instead of the image there is a black box. Is there anyway to get a black border such that when I am printing copies of this I don't waste precious black ink.

Comment: Your precious black ink, haha

Comment: @Daniel in these hard financial times, every penny counts

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \def\Ginclude@graphics#1{%
      \begingroup\fboxsep=-\fboxrule
      \fbox{\rule{\@ifundefined{Gin@@ewidth}{150pt}{\Gin@@ewidth}}{0pt}%
        \rule{0pt}{\@ifundefined{Gin@@eheight}{100pt}{\Gin@@eheight}}}\endgroup}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I wonder why `graphics` doesn't do that automatically when the draft option is set.

Comment: @Caramdir File a request at www.latex-project.org

Comment: @egreg Any way to wrap this in a macro so that I can call it when I want it? I changed `#1` to `##1` when it is wrapped, but I run into trouble because my includegraphics path is a macro itself. So paths look like `\maclibrary Images/pic.jpg` (`##1`). It works, but not if I want to write the file path to the page e.g. `\parbox{\@ifundefined{Gin@@ewidth}{150pt}{\Gin@@ewidth}}{##1}`

Comment: @macmadness86 Isn't this the `draft` option?

Comment: @egreg Nevermind. I think the problem is my macro expands to underscores! I am foolish for not recognizing that some images have underscores in the filenames! Lesson here that I should have learned a long time ago: file system naming conventions do not overlap with LaTeX character category code conventions!

Answer (score 5):

Since the `demo` option to [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) makes *all* `\includegraphics` commands print a 150pt x 100pt rectangle and there's no way around that easily, you could just redefine the `\includegraphics` command:

```
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}% Remove frame separator/gap
  \framebox{\rule{0pt}{100pt}\rule{150pt}{0pt}}% Framed box of 150pt x 100pt
}
```

Now you can remove the `demo` option from `graphicx` and use the document as is with the same `\framebox`-filled result. Since the command has the same format `\includegraphics[..]{...}`, no further modifications are needed; all arguments (both optional and mandatory) are discarded.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way (albeit slightly overkill with `\tkiz` for drawing the box, but you can adapt the other solutions for the box drawing if that is not desired -- I tend to think `\tikz` first for some reason :-).  The only real enhancement here from the other solutions is to use `\def\DemoOption{demo}` when in demo mode and `\def\DemoOption{}` when not in demo mode.  This could be improved by using a command line option to set `\DemoOption`.

Since the `graphicx` pacakge defines `\def\Ginclude@graphics` when in demo mode, we just need to redfine that after `\begin{document}`:

```
\def\DemoOption{demo}% Use this in demo mode
%\def\DemoOption{}% Use this when done want figures included
\RequirePackage[\DemoOption]{graphicx}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter%
\IfStrEq{\DemoOption}{demo}{%
    \renewcommand{\Ginclude@graphics}[1]{%
      \tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (150pt,100pt);%
}}{}%
\makeatother

\includegraphics{whatever}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the package [`draftfigure`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/draftfigure) to get the same result and modify the display of the switched off figure:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[allfiguresdraft]{draftfigure}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=50pt]{example-image-a}

\includegraphics[draft=false,width=50pt]{example-image-b}

\setdf{content={This figure is switched off.}}
\includegraphics[width=50pt]{example-image-c}

\end{document}
```

[image]