# Placeholder for figure/includegraphics

Tags: graphics

Is there a command that I can use as a placeholder for `\includegraphics`?
I want to use such a placeholder to add the original graphics later.

Comment: You may create a `dummy.jpg` (or dummy.eps) and use this dummy graphic until you have your original one.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30624/4427 for having the `demo` option not printing big blobs.

Comment: @egreg: can you post that one as an answer to this one? I may accept that one.

Comment: Related: [Example images in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231738/example-images-in-latex)

Comment: Wow, not a single tikz answer!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you need individual figures to be omitted rather than all of them, you first copy a dummy figure (called `foo` here) to your figures path, then use as:

```
\includegraphics[draft]{foo}
```

It will display something like:

[image]

It will also save ink, and you can use `\includegraphics` syntax as it is, you just need to replace `foo` and remove `draft` from command.

Comment: I am not sure if the bounding-box computations are reliable. I had some problems with the replacement of default sized boxes for the `draft` mode graphics. By the way, for every picture you can also use `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}`. Turkce gormek ayrica sasirtici :)

Comment: @percusse: actually, although I almost never use default sizes, I omitted `width`, `height` arguments in my example. selamlar efendim :)

Answer (score 198):

It's 2018 now, and this has become very easy.

Simply:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
```

The [`mwe`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mwe) package needs to be installed for this (but it doesn't need to be included in the preamble). If using MiKTex e.g., it will offer to install this package when the document is built.

There are other placeholder images available as well.

Example document from [another StackExchange answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231741/153868):

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}\qquad
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-golden}\qquad
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}

\noindent\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-b} 

\noindent\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-c} 

\noindent\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wish this could be somewhere near the top. :-)

Comment: Compilation always fails when `[draft]` is not given. Can you explain why?

Comment: @Patrick: Not without context. Kindly post a proper question, someone might help then.

Comment: @Patrick: perhaps you're using `\includegraphics[draft][width=3cm]{example-image-a}`, whereas it should be `\includegraphics[draft,width=3cm]{example-image-a}`. That is, use only one pair of block brackets. For others: the `draft` option will only draw a bounding box instead of the actual image (to save ink/toner).

Answer (score 79):

[`todonotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/todonotes) provides the `\missingfigure` command, precisely designed for this case

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{Testing a long text string}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: this doesn't work for me with \includegraphics

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I don't use `\includegraphics` here.

Comment: yes exactly so you have to remove \includegraphics and later re-insert it

Comment: I expected something to use with includegraphics like the others answers

Comment: I don't see why. This is a **placeholder**, you just replace it with the actual content when you get it. it is no different from e.g. removing `[draft]` and putting the actual path in [the accepted solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44398/8547).

Answer (score 32):

It's 2018 now, and this has become even more fun.

Simply:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
```

The `duckuments` package needs to be installed for this. If using MiKTex e.g., it will offer to install this package when the document is built.

Example document from another StackExchange answer:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}

\noindent\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(This post may have been inspired by [Tomas answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413186/36296) :)

Comment: This is fun, works great and respect order with which figures should appear in the documents (\missingfigure does not). Thanks!

Comment: @Rodrigo You're welcome!

Answer (score 25):

Either load the `graphicx` package with the `demo` option or replace `\includegraphics` by, say, `\rule{2cm}{2cm}`.

Comment: IIRC, `\includegraphics[demo,width=<..>,height=<..>]{dummy}` should work as well, i.e. `demo` used locally.

Comment: @Martin: I get `! Package keyval Error: demo undefined.`

Comment: To avoid the black box of \rule{2cm}{2cm} but to keep the simplicity, you can draw just two or three edges of the box with \rule{.1pt}{2cm} \rule{2cm}{.1pt} \rule{.1pt}{2cm}

Comment: @vowel-house-might this is brilliantly simple ! Thanks. Just wanted to highlight for other readers that you cannot get 4 lines with this method (I have tried). But 3 works very well. Also note that the horizontal line cannot be `\linewidth` long, as the others no longer have space. So just put the numbers manually.

Answer (score 25):

I dont't like the *demo* option of the `graphicx` package, because one get some ugly black boxes in the document. And if you want to make a test print you waste a lot of ink and maybe your reviser is wondering about. So I created my own demo mode and just include an empty rectangle with the same size of the original picture. If I want to use the original pictures I comment the definition out and all the pictures will be inserted. For this it is necessary to use the [`picins`](http://ctan.org/pkg/picins) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\def\Ginclude@graphics#1{%
    \parpic(\Gin@@ewidth,\Gin@@eheight)[d]{#1}\picskip{0}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=8cm,height=5cm]{myPictureName.png}%
  \caption{My Picture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where did you get `picins`? It doesn't seem to be a standard package.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt Used to be standard but was removed from TL, I think, for license reasons.

Comment: At http://ctan.org/pkg/picins you can see that picins is standard in MiKTeX (I use MiKTeX) but not in TeXLive. You should install it manually.

Comment: @Holle: Good to know. Could you put the link into the answer though? I think it's a good thing to have there for completeness.

Comment: @Holle How can one insert a `keepaspectratio`?

Comment: @Yiannis Please keep in mind that this approach was intended by the fact that there were no pictures to insert and that we don't want to use the demo mode of the graphicx package. So you don't know the size of the pictures. If you already have the pictures and you don't want to show them in the document you should use the draft option of you documentclass.

Comment: @joseph the evidence it was removed from tl on 2007-01-13, and the licence was checked (other-nonfree) on 2008-05-08; the package remains on ctan, of course, since the author once uploaded it (long enough ago that there are no outstanding records).

Answer (score 21):

You can do without additional packages: just load `graphicx` with the `demo` option and do as explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30624/4427); I repeat the code for completeness:

```
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\makeatletter
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \def\Ginclude@graphics#1{%
      \begingroup\fboxsep=-\fboxrule
      \fbox{\rule{\@ifundefined{Gin@@ewidth}{150pt}{\Gin@@ewidth}}{0pt}%
        \rule{0pt}{\@ifundefined{Gin@@eheight}{100pt}{\Gin@@eheight}}}\endgroup}}
\makeatother
```

Just remove the `demo` option and comment the additional code when you want to include the real graphic files.

This will produce framed rectangles with the specified width and height, but using a predefined dimension when `width=` *and* `height=` are not specified in the options to `\includegraphics`.

Another strategy is to load `graphicx` with the `draft` option, that will read the graphic files for getting their dimensions and print a framed rectangle with the file name in their place

```
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
```

As always, beware of file names with spaces: enclosing the name between double quotes should avoid problems.

Answer (score 11):

Inspired by Holle's answer (avoid a big black toner hungry box), here is one with pgf. The pgf package has a draft option. With it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{pgf}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{pgfpicture}
    \pgftext{\pgfimage[width=5cm,height=4cm]{scratch.png}}
\end{pgfpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

where `scratch.png` is your image. With `draft` as an option to the pgf package this simply looks like a box with the file name:

[image]

Without the draft option, the image is placed as expected.

Comment: Doesn't this just draws a box of X by Y? One would ideally need to be able to measure the actual image and print the box to the resulting dimension (i.e, if only width or height is specified, keepaspectratio etc).

Comment: I agree. It defaults to a 1cm by 1cm box. Perhaps it can be improved, but it's already a peripheral answer.

Answer (score 10):

A better version to hide the entire picture but keep the space is to use the `phantom` command

```
\phantom{\includegraphics[...]{picture}}
```

This avoids white text, could for example be selected in the pdf.

PS: not enough repo to comment on Dennis' answer.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to "hide" the entire picture, but reserve the space, you could use the following lines:

```
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
...
\color{white}
\includegraphics[draft , ...]{picture}
\color{black}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it) or type Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the package [`draftfigure`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/draftfigure) to switch off and modify the display of  figures:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[
      %various options globally available
    ]{draftfigure}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=.5\linewidth}%only for demonstration
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
     \centering
     \setkeys{draftfigure}{content={white box}}
      \includegraphics[draft]{example-image-a}
      \caption{A}\label{A}
     \setkeys{draftfigure}{filename=true}
      \includegraphics[draft]{example-image-b}
      \caption{B}\label{B}
     \setkeys{draftfigure}{content={another white box}}
      \includegraphics[draft]{example-image-c}
      \caption{C}\label{C}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[htb]
     \centering
     \setkeys{draftfigure}{content={white box}}
      \includegraphics[draft]{example-image-a}
      \caption{A}\label{A1}

     \setkeys{draftfigure}{filename=true,
     style={tt},position={right}}
      \includegraphics[draft]{example-image-b}
      \caption{B}\label{B1}

     \setkeys{draftfigure}{content={hidden image},
       style={rm},filename=false,position={center}}
      \includegraphics[draft]{example-image-c}
      \caption{C}\label{C1}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image: examples 1]
[image: examples 2]

Answer (score 3):

I like the simplicity of https://gist.github.com/dpgettings/9635856 (not mine, so credit to the author **dpgettings**):

```
\newcommand{\dummyfig}[1]{
  \centering
  \fbox{
    \begin{minipage}[c][0.33\textheight][c]{0.5\textwidth}
      \centering{#1}
    \end{minipage}
  }
}
```

which can be used as:

```
\begin{figure*}[h]
  \dummyfig{Dummy Figure Label} 
  \caption{Dummy figure caption}
  \label{fig:dummy}
\end{figure*}
```