# Making a fake figure that holds a text box of specified dimensions

Tags: floats, boxes

I think I have seen this done before, but I am not sure. Is there a way to build a fake figure in LaTeX?  I would like to do this while the other figures in the document render correctly.

Ideally, I would like to have a white box with large text in it, and with a black frame around it. It would be great to be able to control the height and width of this box.

E.g.

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
%% Code to make a fake text box
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{figure}
```

I am loading TikZ in the document, so I can use solutions that may require it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to use `\fbox{Dummy}` with a `\resizebox{<width>}{<height>}{<content>}`. Maybe playcing the `\fbox` on the outside.

It is even easier and more flexible with my `adjustbox` package, e.g.:

```
\adjustbox{margin=1em,width=.9\textwidth,set height=10cm,frame,center}{Dummy}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!t]
    \centering
    \adjustbox{margin=1em,width=\textwidth,set height=4cm,set depth=4cm,frame,center}{Dummy}
    \caption{Dummy}
    \label{fig:dummy}
\end{figure}


\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: If multi-line text is required add e.g. a `minipage=<width>` or similar key at the very beginning.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: Yes, thanks. My mistake. Fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

Another way could be using a `\fbox` to frame a `\parbox` (using the second optional argument you can control the height):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\FramedBox[3]{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
  \fbox{\parbox[t][#1][c]{#2}{\centering\huge #3}}}

\begin{document}

\FramedBox{4cm}{4cm}{Some text}

\FramedBox{2cm}{8cm}{Some text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way: an `\fbox` containing invisible rules as high and wide as specified

```
\newcommand{\fakebox}[2]{% #1 = width, #2 = height
  {\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\fbox{\rule{0pt}{#2}\rule{#1}{0pt}}}}

\fakebox{3cm}{2cm}
```

The initial setting will add no additional width or height due to the borders.

Adding a word is not difficult: I would never use a large word, just a small one in a corner to make clear that this is only a placeholder

```
\newcommand{\fakebox}[2]{% #1 = width, #2 = height
  {\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\fbox{\makebox[0pt][r]{\kern2\fboxrule\tiny dummy}%
     \rule{0pt}{#2}\rule{#1}{0pt}}}}
```

Comment: There is a `\phantombox{<width>}{<height>}{<depth}` macro provided by `adjustbox`, which could be placed in a `\frame` or `\fbox`. You can also reduce the dimensions to compensate for the frame rule width and separation.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is very similar to my solution for this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44199/10570 . It uses the `picins` package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{picins}

\def\pictureBox#1#2#3{%
    \parpic(#1,#2)[d]{#3}\picskip{0}%
}%


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \pictureBox{8cm}{5cm}{Here is the text.}
    \caption{My placholder}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

An other very simple solution may be to use the `\missingfigure` command of the `todonotes` package.
You can adjust the width and height of the figure with the `figwidth`and `figheight` parameters :
`\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{Testing a long text string}`
You can also change the color of the background with the `figheight`parameter.