# Add and align photo placeholder with title

Tags: graphics, positioning, titles, cv, resume

I am trying to learn TeX and I need to add a photo placeholder and align it with a title.

I have the following code

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\begin{document}
\name{\LARGE Person's name}
\photo[64pt][0.15pt]{picture}

\end{document}
```

And I would like to have the following output:
[image: desired output]

The code above throws me an error when using `\photo[64pt][0.15pt]{picture}`.
By the way, this is for a CV with photo of the subject in German style (Lebenslauf).

How can I achieve this?
I was also looking at [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44195/placeholder-for-figure-includegraphics) but I don't know how to make the placeholder stand above the line of the title.

Comment: \photo is not standard latex, but rather is peculiar to some document classes.  I couldn't find any equivalent for res class.  You might want to look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae

Comment: I saw an example on the web where they used moderncv package, but I wanted to do it from scratch. I guess that's where the '\photo' comes from.

Comment: In that case use article and format it yourself.  The answer below is one approach.  Other formatting commands of interest are \makebox and \raisebox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend writing a resume in the default `article` document class. However, since you're using [`res`](http://ctan.org/pkg/res), you can use the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\namefont}{\bfseries\LARGE}
\begin{document}

\name{\makebox[\textwidth]{Person's name\hfill \includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image}}}
\opening
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a `tabular` type of environment as the `\NameAndPhoto` macro does, or without packages use an `\hfill` between the name and image and then draw the `\rule` yourself:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\NameAndPhoto}[2]{%
    \noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Xr@{}}
        \textbf{\Large #1} & \includegraphics[width=2.0cm,height=1.5cm]{#2} \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
}

\newcommand*{\NameAndPhotoNonTabular}[2]{%
    \noindent%
    \textbf{\Large #1}\hfill\includegraphics[width=2.0cm,height=1.5cm]{#2}%
    \par\vspace{-0.75\baselineskip}%
    \noindent%
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}
}


\begin{document}
\NameAndPhoto{Person's name}{../images/EiffelWide}
\bigskip\par
\NameAndPhotoNonTabular{Person's name}{../images/EiffelWide}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to do it inside the '\name' tag? I tried adding '\includegraphics[width=2.0cm,height=1.5cm]{photo.jpg}' to it but it's left aligned whereas I would like it to be right aligned, that is with the end (or near it) of the line generated by '\name'.

Comment: @OneEyeQuestion: That depends on what the definition of `\name` is? If the only purpose of `\name` is to typeset the name in bold, the the macros I provided do that so no need to use `\name`.

Comment: @PeterGrill There's is an inconvenient with your approach and is that because I am using 'res' (didn't know what was that, but Werner pointed outed correctly) it draws automatically the line. If I use your method 2 things happen: 1) The name isn't properly aligned with the line drawn, that is there is more space between the line and the name. 2) The name is aligned with the contents of the document which begin almost half-way the 'Person's name'. (But I guess this isn't your fault since you couldn't see 'res'). Finally I accept Werner's answer since it is simpler.