# Image placeholder as in \includegraphics[draft], but without path appearing

Tags: graphics

I want to upload a talk slides to a repository where all material submitted shall be under a certain license. For this, I need to exclude certain images present in the actually sued slides for which the license does not apply, adn have a placeholder instead. 
`\includegraphics[draft,..` pretty much does what I want, only that the actual command in my document is something like

```
\includegraphics[draft,widht=0.7\textwidth]{../../../talks/1999/acapulco/filename}
```

which results in the full path being displayed in, and exceeding the placeholder box.

Can I somehow prevent the path from being displayed? It is both ugly and contains more information than I want to convey. Filename alone would be ok, but is not required. If I remove `\includegraphics` entirely, the layout changes and/or I would have to manually size and place the placeholder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that adds a `noincl` key:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{noincl}[true]{%
  \lowercase{\Gin@boolkey{#1}}{draft}%
  \lowercase{\Gin@boolkey{#1}}{noincl}%
}
\newif\ifGin@noincl

\patchcmd{\Gin@setfile}{\hb@xt@}{\noinc@box{#3}}{}{}

\def\noinc@box#1#2#3{%
  \ifGin@noincl
    \do@noinc@box{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  \else
    \hb@xt@#2{#3}
  \fi
}

\def\do@noinc@box#1#2#3{%
  \hb@xt@\Gin@req@width{%
    \vrule\hss
    \vbox to \Gin@req@height{%
      \hrule \@width \Gin@req@width
      \vss
      \edef\@tempa{#1}%
      \expandafter\filename@parse\expandafter{\@tempa}%
      \rlap{%
        \kern3\p@
        \parbox{\dimexpr\Gin@req@width-6\p@}{
          \raggedright\footnotesize Not included for copyright reasons
        }%
      }%
      \vss
      \rlap{\kern3\p@ \tiny\ttfamily\filename@base.\filename@ext}%
      \vss
      \hrule}%
    \hss\vrule}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[noincl,width=4cm]{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`todonotes` has a facility to show missing figures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[htb]
    \missingfigure[figwidth=0.7\textwidth]{My first figure}
    \missingfigure[figheight=6cm]{}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Like `todonotes` does, you could just include some TikZ rectangle. I made some macro for you, which gets the dimensions of the actual picture and sets them to the dummy node:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newif\ifdraft
\drafttrue
%\draftfalse
\newsavebox\imagebox
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand \includedraftpic { o m }{%
    \sbox\imagebox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
    \ifdraft
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \node[draw, text width=\the\wd\imagebox,minimum height=\the\ht\imagebox, align=center, inner sep=0]{removed for copy right reasons};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \else
    \usebox\imagebox
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includedraftpic[widht=0.7\textwidth]{../../../talks/1999/acapulco/filename}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

All you have to do now is to toggle the conditionals `draftfalse` or `drafttrue`.

[image]

Comment: "...toggle the conditionals" would set it for the whole document, right?

Comment: Yes, but you can change it during the document.

Comment: @arne.b yes, correct. But it will only be recognized by my new macro. If you like, you can put other stuff between `\ifdraft .. \else ... \fi` anywhere in your document. Like this, you have your own draft mode and can include/exclude anything you please.

Comment: you load the image three times. I think something like `\newsavebox\imagebox` and then `\savebox\imagebox{\includegraphics{imagefile}}\ifdraft\missingfigure[figwidth=\the\wd\imagebox,figheight=\the\ht\imagebox]{removed}\else\usebox\imagebox\fi` should be possible (not tested).

Comment: @tohecz Yes, thats much more efficient. Thank you. I added that.

Comment: Thank you, got your point now. Unfortunately, the grey box is half a figure height off (moved down) for me (no problem, I could just turn it off), and there does not seem to be [an option](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/todonotes.pdf) to get rid of the "yield" sign, is there?

Comment: @arne.b please see my complete revision. As `todonotes` is just setting some TikZ node for you, you can just write your own TikZ stuff which may look as you like. I just made a boring black rectangle without a fill here. You may insert what ever style you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\Demo{%
  \def\Ginclude@graphics##1{%
      \rule{\@ifundefined{Gin@@ewidth}{150pt}{\Gin@@ewidth}}%
      {\@ifundefined{Gin@@eheight}{100pt}{\Gin@@eheight}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering\Demo
  \includegraphics[width=8cm,height=5cm]{Koala_whatever}%
  \caption{My Picture}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=8cm,height=5cm]{tiger}%
  \caption{My Picture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can slightly change [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44199/5042) to not display the filename and use it as a command:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\imagedraftmode}{
\def\Ginclude@graphics##1{%
    \parpic(\Gin@@ewidth,\Gin@@eheight)[d]{}\picskip{0}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\imagedraftmode
  \includegraphics[width=8cm,height=5cm]{Koala}%
  \caption{My Picture}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=8cm,height=5cm]{Koala}%
  \caption{My Picture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this just gives me `! Undefined control sequence.
\Ginclude@graphics #1->\parpic (\Gin@@ewidth ,\Gin@@eheight )[d]{}\picskip {0}`.

Comment: @arne.b do you have the picins package installed?