# Tell pdflatex to escape/replace missing figures

Tags: graphics, pdftex, compiling, layout

Sometimes, we want to replace a missing/forgot-to-upload figure with blanks or some placeholder

This can be done by changing the code and use the `mwe` package `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}`, see, [Placeholder for figure/includegraphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44195/placeholder-for-figure-includegraphics)

But, I want to achieve this feature **without modifying the tex code**. Because in many version control cases, I'm not allowed to change the code.

Instead, is it possible to add extra options to the `pdflatex` command so that the missing figure is replaced by some placeholder? I.e., I want to do this feature in the "compiler" level.

Comment: The `demo` option of the `graphicx` package might be useful. Please note that it will replace all `\includegraphics` images with a black rectangle, regardless of wether the corresponding image is a vailalble or not.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the image exists with `\IfFileExists`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,todonotes}
\def\imgcond#1{
\IfFileExists{#1}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{#1}}{
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}}
\parskip1em

\begin{document}

\imgcond{example-image-a}

\imgcond{whatever}

\imgcond{anything}

\end{document}
```