# graphicx: New Option to be Able to Handle Missing Files (No Error)

Tags: graphics

I would like to have a **new option** in the `\includegraphics`command. The idea ist that there is **no error when the file does not exist** - maybe just a friendly warning.

Ideally, the file extension is not needed (to be flexible in the future) but if it's needed that's also ok (at the moment it's not necessary).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[myDoNotComplainIfFileIsMissing]{MyFileThatMayOrMayNotExist.ext}

\end{document}
```

### Possible duplicates

- [Use "default" figure if file is missing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39982)
- [Compile when images are missing completely BUT turn on certain images?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349343)

Comment: You can define a new command `\newcommand{\ncigraphics}[1]{\iffileexists{#1}{\includegrapchics{#1}}{}`.  Unfortunately you have to define the file extension.  And you have to add some more magic, to hand over the optional arguments for the includegraphics command.

Comment: @Jan Thanks for the comment. I just chatted to the developer of the graphics package and he pointed out some duplicate questions.

Comment: Can we mark it as duplicate then?

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes. Do you keep track? :)

Comment: I just looked around. We have a long list of unanswered questions. It needs cleaning every once in a while.